# Can I change the traceroute to a certain IP?

Tags: networking, internet, routing, traceroute

I like to play the game League of Legends but lately have gotten unacceptable amounts of latency (400+ ping). After finding out the game server's IP (95.172.65.165) I tried to traceroute it to see if there are any problems. As it turns out, there are:

```
C:\>tracert 95.172.65.165

Tracing route to 95.172.65.165 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]
  2    25 ms    27 ms    25 ms  lo1.dr8.d12.xs4all.net [194.109.5.205]
  3    34 ms    28 ms    27 ms  1418.ae3.xr4.1d12.xs4all.net [194.109.7.17]
  4    43 ms    26 ms    25 ms  0.so-0-2-0.xr1.tc2.xs4all.net [194.109.5.10]
  5    25 ms    53 ms    30 ms  xe-1-3-0.ams12.ip4.tinet.net [77.67.74.209]
  6    31 ms    32 ms    37 ms  xe-3-0-0.fra23.ip4.tinet.net [89.149.185.110]
  7    33 ms    32 ms    33 ms  internap-gw.ip4.tinet.net [77.67.73.166]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  *snip*

 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

As you can see it never finishes. I have tried everything on my side to improve the connection, but I have ruled out everything (network card drivers, modem firmware, line issues). I have ~50 ping with any other european server, and I used to have around that with this one too. But since two weeks the latency has skyrocketed. And I'm not the only one, many (mostly italian) people report the same issue, with the same traceroute stuck on internap-gw.ip4.tinet.net.

Is there anything I can do to bypass this and get my previously good connection back?

Comment: Traceroute does not always finish without timing out as some internet routers do not respond to ICMP messages.  It's normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only ways to change your routing to a specific destination are to use some kind of proxy or a different ISP. Routing is pretty much determined by peering arrangements between ISPs.

The fact that traceroute never ends just means that the last router or last few routers are not reporting back packet TTL expiry, it doesn't explain the overall latency (your 400ms ping).

Comment: Yes. That's a perfectly normal traceroute and doesn't indicate any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also request that your ISP (or Tinet) reroute your traffic using alternate ISP peers. I have done this once or twice in the past. Above, where Tracert is going to after Tinet is the ISP that is unresponsive. Ping however automatically reroutes and finds an alternate route (if any exist) to the final Destination IP. The fact that ping works means that there is a working connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is *technically* possible.

You would need to setup your local network with a dummy ISP / DNS server, with the routes pre preprogrammed in for a specific IP destination.

An easy example: on windows, you can bypass DNS by editing the "hosts file". A classic way to circumvent DNS based website blockers.

The hosts file is basically a mini DNS server that lives on your windows computer. Which means that any address listed within the file bypasses DNS, so 8.8.8.8 (Google) cannot see your traffic to that particular page.

E.G.

If IP: [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) -> "123.123.123.123"

Taking this a step further: You would need to set up redirects from one IP to the next on your computer using a similar technique used with the hosts file.

Then in the hosts file /or through some other configuration you could do a link (In Theory), that would in essence bypass the DNS routing. (Your ISP cannot e bypassed, but you *can* remove the need to query your ISP in the first place. ISPs are just middle men between you and your line provisioner anyways.)

[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) -> 255.255.255.255 -> 123.123.123.123

I'll follow up on this post if anyone is interested in a practical method example.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP's question was about, though? You can change which address a domain name points to, but you can't really change where 95.172.65.165 goes using this method.